# How to write numbers one after the other in different context

Tags: numbers

Sorry if the title is poor. I am having a hard time thinking of a good title.

If I wanted to say something like:

"We will have 5 two-hour sessions".

Is there a proper way of listing this?

- "Five 2-hour sessions"?
- "5 2-hour sessions"?
- "5 two-hour sessions"?
- "Five two-hour sessions"?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/when-to-spell-out-numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many style guides (some? My papers must conform to Turabian's *Manual*) say to either use numerals or spell out the numbers—don't mix and match formats. That said, I find *five 2-hour sessions* to be more readable than *five two-hour sessions*.

Comment: I agree, and I also find both better than "5 two-hour sessions" and "5 2-hour sessions".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in general it is a good idea to not mix formats, *but* if the phrase starts a sentence, then you'll want to spell out the first number, *then* by convention, the second number should be numeric (as it is less than 20 or whatever limit is set by your style guide).

On the other hand, you also *should* mix formats if it would otherwise be confusing. Also I've heard that mixing formats should be done if you are counting different kinds of things, again, just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previously-mentioned preference for *five 2-hour sessions*, with "5 two-hour sessions" nearby in preference.  However, what I would do for a case like this is to reword the phrase as either of the following.

> five sessions of two hours each...
>   two-hour sessions, five in number...